# Is there any way to reduce flutter app size

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

My query is regarding Flutter App Size
I am building an application currently only for android user
So can i remove the entire IOS folder thing (i am beginner so please do not bother if it seems silly)
Or any other alternative to reduce app size
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean the bundle size (processed flutter code to application) or the repository size? Would you mind telling the reason why you want to reduce the size of something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are a little bit confused on this one. When you are developing an app your application folder might weight a lot depending on packages and assets you are using but when you are [building and releasing an Android app](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android) the development kit will only use the necessary files and export a very tiny sized appbundle compared to your development folder.

**Example** they are the same application;

1. Left side is built Android app
2. Right side is development folder

[image]

Comment: Yes sir @SLendeR you are right . i got confused in it . but sir i did $ flutter build apk 
and then in build-->app--> app release apk was created which i transferred to my mobile device and installed it 
as a file it was just 18MB 
but when downloaded it took storage space of 100MB + data storage of 40MB
moreover i didnt have any such thing in my app which would take data storage in app 
everything is dynamically called using json and nothing as such consuming extra storage

Answer (score 1):

The best way is build bundle

```
flutter build appbundle
```

Or build apk and split

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

When u split the apk the Android build three differents apk (separated by arch).

This reduce the apk size

https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle